# Meteor app multiple themes support

Tags: meteor

I am trying to build a Meteor app which should support two totally different themes (members - admin), each theme include its own separate css, LESS, JS and html files. So I was wondering does Meteor support multiple client themes and dynamic switching between themes? Thanks

Comment: If the HTML is completely different then I would say this is more than just a "theme" but rather an entirely different *layout*. You can render different templates depending on the user's roles, and then you can use a class on a container element to specify which CSS styles should be applied.

Comment: @sbking yes exactly, the html is also different so it is different layout(s). Is it possible to dynamically load different layouts in the Meteor app? In other words for example to have say set A of routes to load a specific layout, css, UI js and set B of routes to load another specific layout, css and UI js files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use Controllers using the iron:router package to achieve what you are looking for.

```
meteor add iron:router
```

Create your layouts:

```
<template name="AdminLayout">
    <div>
        {{> yield}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="MemberLayout">
    <div>
        {{> yield}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Then define your controllers:

```
AdminController = RouteController.extend({
    layoutTemplate: 'AdminLayout'
});

MemberController = RouteController.extend({
    layoutTemplate: 'MemberLayout'
});
```

And then you can define your routes and specify the controller they use:

```
Router.route('/admin', {
    controller: 'AdminController'
});

Router.route('/', {
    controller: 'MemberController'
});
```

Then just create separate templates using the different css, js, and whatnot.

You can read more about the package here: [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md)