# How to create a theme framework (like Wordpress') for a Meteor project

Tags: wordpress, meteor, frameworks, themes, wordpress-theming

We would like to create a theme framework for a Meteor project ---- similar to how Wordpress enables custom theming.

I've read the following posts suggesting possibly [Iron Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399792/meteor-app-multiple-themes-support) or [If Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29486782/meteorjs-change-between-many-ui-frameworks), and the meteor-template-extension [package](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/template-extension) seems to be quite popular as well.

Any input or guidance would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### tl; dr

You can't create themes for Meteor project itself, you have ability to customize existing packages that are used for UI or provide yourself.

### Explanation

WordPress is CMS, which has a lot of core features out of the box. So you can just customize view of these parts.

Meteor then is framework, so there are no UI components shared between different projects, because every project is unique and you have nothing to customize.

But, there is a lot of widely used packages based on Blaze templates and you can create themes for them editing source code, e.g [ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3](https://atmospherejs.com/ian/accounts-ui-bootstrap-3).

Also look at [Orion](http://www.orionjs.org/) - Meteor based CMS, which have at least two [themes](http://docs.orionjs.org/) (Materialize and Bootstrap) and can be extended by another as well.

### UPD

As clear after your comment we are talking about a feature in your own project. I can agree with people [in question you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29486782/meteorjs-change-between-many-ui-frameworks) - you are able to use many `{{#if smth}}` blocks to dynamicaly load wanted templates, but it is a lot of work near to create two instances of frontend.

It may look something like that:

```html
<template name="material-button">
    <a id="myBtn" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">
        Button!
    </a>
</template>

<template name="bs-button">
    <button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-primary">
        Button!
    </button>
</template>

<template name="button">
    {{#if material}}
        {{> material-button}}
    {{else}}
        {{> bs-button}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

```js
Template.button.helpers({
    material: function() {
        // true or false depending on user choice
        return Session.get('material');
    }
});
```

As for routing and layouts - take a look at [recommended in Meteor Guide `flow-router`](http://guide.meteor.com/routing.html#flow-router). You can take user preferred theme in layout and then pass it down to allnested templates as argument.

Comment: However, we don't want to create a theme-framework for Meteor, we want to create a theme framework for our specific Meteor project, which already does have defined UI components.  Does this change your response?